# Synchronizing content with divs on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, html, workflow, synchronization

I am trying to make my workflow easier. This is why I am looking for a possibilty to have one HTML or JavaScript file that loads into the sidebar of each of my pages.

I am thinking of creating a file called for example: "sidebar.html" or "sidebar.js".

And on my normal pages (about.html, music.html, etc...) I have a div with id and/or class "sidebar". This div is the exact same on each page. How can I make the sidebar.html/sidebar.js load into those divs?

That way when I want to update my sidebar, I would only have to change the sidebar.html/sidebar.js and would not have to open each page and manually change it.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: AngularJs would be a great way to manage this sort of scenario with a custom directive called <side-bar></side-bar>. There is some overhead to this be well worth the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML files dont have an include feature as you are expecting. However there are many options.

in your about.html have your div`<div id="sidebar"></div>`, now send an ajax request to `sidebar.html` and append the response in you div.

Other option is to have an iframe in your div

`<div id="sidebar"> <iframe src="sidebar.html"></iframe><div/>`